# Hoy to display the first and last number of the axis in a GraphView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am using a small GraphView but the labels of the numbers of the X and Y axis are heaped. Is there a way to only show the first and the last number?[image]

Comment: I personally use `graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsAngle(15);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph.getViewport().setMinY(minValueY);
graph.getViewport().setMaxY(maxValueY);

graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph.getViewport().setMinX(minValueX);
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(maxValueX);

graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumVerticalLabels(2);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(2);
```